# How to compare two matrices by checking log result

Tags: matlab

I have two matrices A and B. I want to compare values of each element in matrix A and elements in matrix B. If the log result of ratio element in matrix A and matrix B is below than zero (0),the value of the element in matrix A will change to 0,otherwise it does not change. For example:

```
A =[1 2;3 4];
B =[1 9;1 0];
```

Then when I run code, it returns:

```
A=[1 0;3 4]
```

Because I will check ratio of A./B so some element of B have 0 value,hence A./B is not correct. This is my code. But I think it is not correct

```
   A =[1 2;3 4];
   B =[1 9;1 0];
   A(log(A./B)<0)=0
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to compute the ratio, or its logarithm: just compare `A` and `B`:

```
A(A<B) = 0;
```

Comment: My example is very simple. But in the real image, this array is as normal distribution, so it is has value vary small. This is reason why  I take log. On other hand, Please think this code similar as Bayesian decision rule for two normal distribution

Comment: @user3051460 Whichever values you have, or whichever interpretation they have, the logic is the same: log(x/y) is negative if and only if x < y. So my answer still applies